# Excluding HTTP/1.1 headers from buffer

Tags: java, http, sockets

I want to download an image using socket. I am currently able to do this, but incoming HTTP/1.1 headers are the only problem. Is there an easy way to exclude these headers from buffer so that the file content only contains encrypted image?

```
void readImage() throws IOException
{
    socket = new Socket("wlab.cs.bilkent.edu.tr", 80);

    DataOutputStream bw = new DataOutputStream(new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
    bw.writeBytes("GET /~alper/pa2/images/ref2.jpg HTTP/1.1\n");
    bw.writeBytes("Host: wlab.cs.bilkent.edu.tr:80\n\n");

    File file = new File("img20.jpg");
    file.createNewFile();

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);

    int count;

    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
    {
      dos.write(buffer, 0, count);
      dos.flush();
    }
    dos.close(); 

    System.out.println("image transfer done");
    socket.close();     
}
```

Downloaded image contains these lines at the top:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 30 Dec 2011 18:30:50 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (Debian) mod_jk/1.2.18 mod_python/3.2.10 Python/2.4.4 PHP/5.2.0-8+etch4 mod_ssl/2.2.3 OpenSSL/0.9.8c mod_perl/2.0.2 Perl/v5.8.8
Last-Modified: Tue, 20 Dec 2011 19:12:23 GMT
ETag: "502811-6b0e-4b48ad8d273c0"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 27406
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you not use [`HttpURLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) instead to save yourself the hassle of handling the HTTP protocol?

Then you are free to only deal with your own data in the HTTP message body.

But @Skip Head is right, the headers end with `CRLF`. See the following in the HTTP spec.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html

```
    generic-message = start-line
                      *(message-header CRLF)
                      CRLF
                      [ message-body ]
    start-line      = Request-Line | Status-Line
```

Comment: Yes, but I need to find a way not to include headers in a file while handling this task via sockets. HttpURLConnection or such like built-in classes may be alternatives but not helpful for me. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Ok, then read the data until you get CRLFCRLF (CRLF x 2). What follows next will be the HTTP message body. But be warned that in theory this body can be encoded and may not be the raw data you want. E.g. chunked - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding. That is why I'd recommend a dedicated HTTP class/library.

Comment: Just curious, why don't you find HttpURLConnection helpful? It has lots of features like automatic retry and connection pooling that increase the reliability of your app.

Answer (score 0):

The headers end in a blank line.